# Question on the Lebesgue measure and Geometric measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

Let $S\subset\mathbb R^d$ be a subset. There can be done all the hypotheses one wants on the set $S$. But, at the moment, suppose that $S$ is closed and $\partial S$ is compact. Let us define

$$
t_x:=\inf\{t\geq0:\Phi(x, 0, t)\in \partial S\},
$$
where $\Phi(x, 0, t)$ is the flow solving the following ODE system
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_s\Phi(x, s)=b(\Phi(x, s), s)\\
\Phi(x, 0)=x
\end{cases}.
$$
The field $b$ is assumed to be Lipschitz continuous in space-time and bounded. Now, for $s\in[0, T]$ ($T>0$ is fixed) let us define the set
$$
\mathcal B(s):=\{x\in\mathbb R^d:t_x\leq s\}
$$
which is such that
$$
s_1\leq s_2\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\mathcal B(s_1)\subseteq\mathcal B(s_2).\qquad(\star)
$$
I proved that:

- the map $s\longmapsto\mathcal L^d(\mathcal B(s))$, where $\mathcal L^d$ is the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, is continuous. Moreover, thanks to $(\star)$ it is increasing too.
- denoted by $\rho$ the Hausdorff distance, $\rho(\mathcal B(s'), \mathcal B(s))\leq L|s'-s|$ for some $L>0$.

I want to prove that the map $s\longmapsto\mathcal L^d(\mathcal B(s))$ is Lipschitz continuous, that is there exists $L>0$ such that
$$
\mathcal L^d(\mathcal B(s')\setminus\mathcal B(s))\leq L|s'-s|.
$$

I expect that it is true but I cannot prove it. This would be true if
$$
\mathcal L^d(\mathcal B(s')\setminus\mathcal B(s))\leq C\rho(\mathcal B(s'), \mathcal B(s))\ \ \text{for some}\ \ C>0
$$
but this is not true in general (think to two concentric balls for example). Some helps?

Thank You